# How to remove API logic from view in Rails Way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api

I would like to remove this logic:

```
Suitcase::Hotel.find(id: hotel.id).images.first.url
```

from view.

https://gist.github.com/2719479

I dont have model Hotel. I get this url via API using Suitcase gem.

Problem is because 
`hotel` is from `@hotels = Suitcase::Hotel.find(location: "%#{headed}%")` and API recevie me images only if do `Suitcase::Hotel.find(id: hotel.id)`

Comment: in def find_hotels you should use @hotels and not hotels

Answer (score 1):

Is adding:

```
@hotel = Suitcase::Hotel.find(id: hotel.id)
```

to `#show` action doesn't work?

**EDIT:**
In that case make an helper:

```
def hotel_image_url(hotel)
  Suitcase::Hotel.find(id: hotel.id).images.first.url
end
```

But as I can see [here](https://github.com/thoughtfusion/suitcase/blob/master/lib/suitcase/hotel/hotel.rb#L104) you can simply write in controller:

```
@hotels_data = Suitcase::Hotel.find(ids: @hotels.map(&:id))
```

Or to be more elegant add to your model (or create decorator (it's better option)):

```
def photo
  Suitcase::Hotel.find(id: self.id).images.first.url
end
```

Comment: Not perfect if this is needed in more than one controller

Comment: ```@hotels_data = Suitcase::Hotel.find(ids: @hotels.map(&:id))``` This doesn`t allow me to get images.first.url but i use decorator for this. Thanks.

Comment: When i`m trying to create photo decorator i get ```undefined method `photo' for #<Class:0x007fc6b4c65ac0>``` How to implement this ??

Answer (score 1):

If `Suitcase::Hotel.find(id: hotel.id).images.first.url` works then i would guess `hotel.images.first.url` will work too if `hotel` is an hotel instance.

Comment: No, because hotel is from ```@hotels = Suitcase::Hotel.find(location: "%#{headed}%")``` and API recevie me images only if do ```Suitcase::Hotel.find(id: hotel.id)```

Comment: So your making a API call (over the internet?) in each iteration of the hotels view loop? i took a quick look at the suitcase API and there is a `find_by_ids` method, maybe use that instead in the controller?

Comment: hi, but this still not gives me images.url and i have to get hotel details via ```Suitcase::Hotel.find(id: hotel.id).images.first.url```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work, not sure about the second option

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :headed, :children, :localization, :arriving_date, :leaving_date, :rooms, :adults
  def hotels
    @hotels ||= find_hotels
  end

private

  def find_hotels
    return unless headed.present?
    @hotels = Suitcase::Hotel.find(location: "%#{headed}%")
    @hotels.each do |hotel|
      def hotel.image_url
        Suitcase::Hotel.find(id: hotel.id).images.first.url
      end
    end
  end
end



# or this, but I'm not sure if this works

@hotels.each do |hotel|
  image_url =  Suitcase::Hotel.find(id: hotel.id).images.first.url
  def hotel.image_url
    image_url
  end
end
```